# How to run Application Pool in 64bit mode?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, application-pool

How can I run an Application Pool in 64bit mode on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with IIS7 Installed ?

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not tell it to run in 64 bit mode, you only tell it if you want to run it in 32 bit mode.   By default it should run in 64 bit.

Comment: by default mine is set to 64. IIS is running in 64mode. But Application is running in 32bit, please do you have any idea why this?